# CLI still asking to try Ionic 4 beta

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

On 23/01/2019 ionic 4 released. Today I updated the cli through `npm install -g ionic`  But cli still asking to try ionic 4 beta. I am starting a new project and I don't want any beta bug. Help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: try with flag sudo npm install -g ionic@latest

Comment: No luck. After trying this `sudo npm install -g ionic@latest`  its says  `ionic@4.9.0`.  but `ionic -v` is still `4.4.0` and also ionic 4 is in `beta`.

Comment: Did you check using the command? > ionic info

Comment: I did. still `4.4.0`. I uninstalled ionic using sudo npm uninstall -g ionic. After that `ionic info` still says `4.4.0`. Why this happens